# Question about GeoLocation and watchposition

Tags: json, post, geolocation, tracking

This link (https://james-priest.github.io/100-days-of-code-log-r2/CH14-Geolocation.html) describes the GeoLocation and watchposition very well. but I have a question
If I need to track someone else's location, how can I send someone else's location to watchPosition?
I would be grateful if you could help me

I have an idea, make a page (like index.html) that gets the person's current position and sends it to the viewer's page (viewer.html) with 'json post' to 'watchposition'. is it correct?